# How is daylight savings time handled? Should I worry about it?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand what happens when I schedule an alarm, using a time calculated by the Calendar class, when daylight savings date is hit? Does the AlarmManager handle the hour change correctly? I don't see the Calendar class adding any daylight savings time according to my tests.

**Example:**
Today is March 9th and I use the following to calculate my alarm time for the next day March 10th the start of daylight savings time at 2am:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// set the time alarm should be triggered
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

long triggerTimeMs = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is really down to your phone settings. If you phone handles daylight saving then you should be able to compare with the phone time directly without worrying about it.

For example

BEFORE Daylight Saving: alarm A at time T

AFTER Daylight Saving: compare time T to time that's on the phone, which is updated automatically.

Comment: Yes, my device does use daylight savings. The question is more or less how does the OS handle the time change? Two things; 1. Do scheduled alarms get updated by the OS when time change happens? 2. Does the Calendar handle time change automatically? From my test it seems it doesn't.